# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined - Discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

(novice in coding, i just follow tutorials and try to understand and learn at the same time)
I recently wanted to code my own Discord bot but i had an issue with the event handler part so i tried another method but now i have another issue.

Instead of responding "pong" to "p!ping", it says :

> client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
> ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
>
> at Object.execute (.../events/message.js:18:23)
>
> at Client.<anonymous (.../main.js:19:44)

I also tried to replace

`client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);` with

`client.commands.cache.get('ping').execute(message, args);` or even `client.commands.find('ping').execute(message, args);` but it says *"TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined - Discord bot"* or even

**Main file :**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const config = require('./config.json');
const {prefix, token} = require('./config.json')


const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();



const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
};


const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    // set a new item in the Collection
    // with the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
};

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

    try {
        client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});


client.login(token);

client.on("ready", () => {
  client.user.setPresence({
      activity: { 
      name: 'p!',
      type: 'WATCHING'
      },status: 'idle'
  });
});
```

**Message.js:**

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = 'p!';

module.exports = {
   name: 'message',
    execute(message) { 
      
    console.log(`${message.author.tag} in #${message.channel.name} sent: ${message.content}`);

    
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase ();

    if (command === 'ping'){
      client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'help'){
      client.commands.get('trick').execute(message, args);
     } 
   }
};
```

**ping.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Ping!',
    execute(message, args) {
        message.channel.send('pong');
    },
};
```

I hope that the informations i provided were helpful. If it's a small mistake such as a missing `;` i'm sorry for wasting your time. Thank you in advance

Comment: I believe you just forgot to create `client.commands`  property in `Message.js`.

Comment: now it says this  ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the

`if (command === 'ping'){` with

`` if (command === `${prefix}ping`){ ``

and it works, i think i just have to do that with all the commands.
If you have an easier solution please feel free to share it or if you found the issue with the code please tell me. (because before it worked without this modification),

thank you

Answer (score 0):

found an easier way like that theres no need to type a new line ( `if (command === 'ping'){ client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);`)

this is what my
**Message.js** file looks like now :

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();


module.exports = (Discord, client, message) => {
  const {prefix} = require('../config.json');
  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase ();

  const command = client.commands.get(cmd) || client.commands.find (a => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));

  if(command) command.execute(client, message, args, Discord);

    
};
```